# Creating a only one ListAdapter to all activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a doubt about ListAdapter. When I create a ListAdapter I need always recriate using `new` or I should create only once.

For example.

```
private void addListAdapter(){
   MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<String>();   
   listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

In this example I'll always invoke `addListAdapter()` to recriate my adapter. I want knows if I should create this `myAdapter` only once and can use in all activity.

example

```
private MyAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<String>(); 
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
} 

/** change list in MyAdapter */
private void changeListAdapter(){
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("Name");
   list.add("LastName");
   myAdapter.changeList(list);
   myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In J2SE/Swing I created a only TableModel in my application, after I just change the List in TableModel. With ListAdapter it's works ?

Comment: You should create ListAdapter only once i.e. in onCreate method of Activity like you did in the second example. That way ListAdapter will be recreated only in situation when Activity will be recreated due to some config changes. So use the same ListAdapter connected to ListView across all the Activity.

Comment: @michal.z alright..it's looks like TableModel of J2SE/Swing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new instance every time you won't get any control on it since you will always reference to a different `MyAdapter` instance, and also is not useful.